# How to dynamically get cell value from SQL table?

Tags: c#, sql

I am new to SQL.

[image: screenshot]

As show in screenshot, how can I get a any specific cell value according to column name?

This query can get you specific cell value according to the column name inside the query (the column name SizeM is fixed inside the query):

```
String s = Item1; 
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT SizeM FROM Table1 where Items = '" +s+ "' ");
```

The result is : JH

But I want to control the column name inside the query, for example I want to place a variable which carries the column name inside the query but if I do this it gives error stating that this variable is not column name, this is the code:

```
var C = SizeM;
String s = Item1; 
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT C FROM Table1 where Items = '" + s+ "' ");
```

Anyone knows how can I control the column name according to a variable which has the column name so I can get any cell value according to this variable. Thank you

Comment: Where is your code when you used a variable for a column name?

Comment: @ Shaharyar.  I updated it

Comment: You didn't use the variable actually. Use it as you used `s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string concatenation in SQL Query string. Here i Take variable Columns 
to store Columns value and concatenate in to SQL Query.

```
string Columns = "SizeL, SizeM"; // Dynamic Columns Goes Here
String s = Item1; 
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT "+ Columns +" FROM Table1 where Items = '" +s+ "' ");
```

Or Even you can use array of columns

```
 string ParaCol = "2,3";
 string[] iCol = ParaCol.split(',');
 string[] Table1Colms = {"Items", "Sizes", "SizeM","SizeL"}; 

 string Columns = "";
 for(int i =0 ; i < Table1Colms.Count() ; i++)
 {
    if(iCol.contains(i.ToString()))
    {
        Columns = Columns  != ""? Columns + ", " +  Table1Colms[i] : Columns + Table1Colms[i];
    }
 }


SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT "+ Columns +" FROM Table1 where Items = '" +s+ "' ");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```
String s = Item1; 
String Column = "SizeL";

SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT " + Column + " FROM Table1 where Items = '" +s+ "' ");
```

Comment: just nit picking, but locally scoped variables should be lower camel case. so, `column` not `Column`

Comment: It would be better if you guide OP for the prevention of SQL Injection.

Comment: @JamesRalston That's not nit picking, that is erroneously assuming your standards are correct and everyone else's is wrong.

Comment: @Shaharyar I almost advised the OP about SQL injection but we don't know where the data is coming from and I didn't want to confuse him.

Comment: @SteveWellens Very true. I guess I was nit-picking because the syntax highlighting makes it appear as a type. Whatever a team decides is best works fine, so long as its consistent.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
String s = Item1; 
string column_name = "SizeS";
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT " + column_name + " FROM Table1 where Items = '" +s+ "' ");
```